# dynamic routing UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following situation:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router','restangular',]);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/cercaPaziente');

$stateProvider
    .state('cercaPaziente',{
      url:'/cercaPaziente',
      templateUrl:'templates/cercaPaziente.html',
      controller:'cercaCtrl'
    })
    .state('cercaPaziente.paziente',{
      url:'/paziente',
      templateUrl:'templates/cercaPaziente.list.html'
    })
    .state('inserisciPaziente',{
      url:'/inserisciPaziente',
      templateUrl:'templates/inserisciPaziente.html'
    })
    .state('modificaPaziente',{
      url:'/modificaPaziente',
      templateUrl:'templates/modificaPaziente.html'
    })


    });
  app.config(function(RestangularProvider){
     RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:3000/');
    });

   app.controller('cercaCtrl', function($scope, Restangular){
     $scope.searcPatient= function searcPatient(){
       var Patients=Restangular.all('pazienti');
       Patients.getList().then(function(patients){
        $scope.allPatients=patients;
  });
}
 });
```

I'd like to pass in the `cercaPaziente.paziente` view the id of my patient  once they are fetched from database so as to create a page for each patient.

I'm pretty new with angular and ui-router so i'm searching any advise to strat-up...
thanks in advance and sorry for my english...

Comment: Do you want to create the routing from database when your app start?

Comment: not necessarily..but any suggestions is appreciated